# What is the difference between traceId and requestId in tracing?

Tags: trace

I am developing with microservices oriented architecture and want to trace. I was googling and I found that istio for example has the fallowing headers:

- x-request-id
- x-b3-traceid
- x-b3-spanid
- x-b3-parentspanid
- x-b3-sampled
- x-b3-flags
- x-ot-span-context

Mainly I want to know the differences between `x-request-id` and `x-b3-traceid`, but ok if someone could share the others headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Istio is using  envoy, I think you can find your answers on this docs https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#id13